# Using jQuery to create parallel html structures

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there a way to easily have parallel html structures using jQuery? For example:

```
<li class="ul-1"> list 1 </li>
<li class="ul-2"> list 2 </li>
<li class="ul-3"> list 3 </li>

<div class="div-1"> div 1 </div>
<div class="div-2"> div 2 </div>
<div class="div-3"> div 3 </div>
```

Putting the div's inside the ul's isn't an option for me, they need to remain separate. I want to do something like `$('.ul-2').show()`, and also have it show $('.div-2). Is there a way to do this without getting a list of classes and parsing the class names?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/index/

Comment: give the li and the divs (the matching ones) the same class? then just show the class all at once

Comment: @SamCreamer the problem with that is, if I do $('li'), then i need to first parse class lists to find the id i want to match, its an extra messy step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As j08691 pointed out, I was able to use jQuery's `index()` function to relate two separate html structures to each other.

http://api.jquery.com/index/